# My .htaccess doesnt working even i put the correct path for DirectoryIndex

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, hosting

Hi im hosting a PHP website to ubuntu server.
-PHP version 7.4, ubuntu 20
So right now my root directory is `html` and i tried to put .htaccess inside `html` but it still showing me the `Index Page` whenever I access my domain

my .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex public/layouts/login.php
```

My directory is like this :
[image: Directory]

When i go to my domain:

[image]

The first directory seems to be "html".

Within the "html" directory, there is another directory named "public".

Within the "public" directory, there are two subdirectories named "include" and "layouts".

The "layouts" directory contains a file named "login.php".

I want to make the login.php as default page when the user enters my server. How can i do that ?

Comment: It would make a lot more sense to have login.php (and any other related files) in the root of the webserver. If the "resources" folder isn't supposed to be public, then move it outside the webserver's root.